# Rails: Why can't I save a new model Instance to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, orm, controller

The #create action of my controller looks like the following. I have no idea, why ruby/rails doesn't take the argument assignments and thus the object I am saving has al "nil"-attributes

```
def create
  @new_page = Page.new 
  @new_page.slug = helpers.create_slug_from_title(params[:title])

  # Yes, I should also save the rest of params and make
  # params a strongparameter object
        
  # how to handle errors on create ?
  begin 
    @new_page.save
  rescue
  end

end
```

I'd be thankful for any hint.

Yours

von Spotz

PS: In the console things don't look different.

```
2.7.0 :038 > pn = Page.new
2.7.0 :039 > pn.slug = "index-page"
2.7.0 :040 > pn.slug
 => "index-page" 
2.7.0 :041 > pn
 => #<Page id: nil, text: nil, slug: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, title: nil, streams_id: nil> 
2.7.0 :042 > pn.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  Page Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "pages" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2021-05-07 17:01:15.111775"], ["updated_at", "2021-05-07 17:01:15.111775"]]
   (31.5ms)  commit transaction
 => true 
2.7.0 :043 > Page.all
Page Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Page id: 1, text: nil, slug: nil, created_at: "2021-05-07 15:40:59", updated_at: "2021-05-07 15:40:59", title: nil, streams_id: nil>, #<Page id: 2, text: nil, slug: nil, created_at: "2021-05-07 16:46:00", updated_at: "2021-05-07 16:46:00", title: nil, streams_id: nil>, #<Page id: 3, text: nil, slug: nil, created_at: "2021-05-07 17:01:15", updated_at: "2021-05-07 17:01:15", title: nil, streams_id: nil>]> 
2.7.0 :044 >
```

PPS: The new controller with the create action and page_params as kindly posted by max

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    
    def home
  end
    
    def show
        @page = Page.where(slug: params[:slug])
    end
    
    def new
        @new_page = Page.new
    end
    
    def edit
        @page = Page.where(slug: params[:slug])
        # error if @page.nil?
    end
    
# POST /pages
  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params) do |page|
      # smelly - should be handled inside the model not by the controller
      page.slug = helpers.create_slug_from_title(page.title)
    end
        
    if @page.save
      redirect_to @page, status: :created
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
        
  private

  def page_params
    params.require(:page)
                    .permit(:slug, :title, :text)
  end
        
end
```

Comment: What does `@new_page.valid?; @new_page.errors` return?

Comment: Hello Sebastian. `(byebug) @new_page.valid?
true
(byebug) @new_page.errors
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007f0c9c8bf6a0 @base=#<Page id: 2, text: nil, slug: nil, created_at: "2021-05-07 16:46:00", updated_at: "2021-05-07 16:46:00", title: nil, streams_id: nil>, @messages={}, @details={}>` But the problem is not the saving. The problem is already the **assignment**. If I try to assign a value and call the same atttribute I just "assigned" a value to, it returns `nil`. Good bye !

Comment: Is there anything in your model that might be modifying the slug before the insertion?

Comment: My guess to why your slug is being saved as nil is that you have `attr_accessor :slug` in your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class PagesController
  # POST /pages
  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params) do |page|
      # smelly - should be handled inside the model not by the controller
      page.slug = helpers.create_slug_from_title(page.title)
    end
    if @page.save
      redirect_to @page, status: :created
    else
      render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def page_params
    params.require(:page)
          .permit(:foo, :bar, :title)
  end
end
```

You handle invalid user input in a classic web app by re-rendering the form. `begin ... rescue` will not work here as `.save` does not raise. `save!` does but its use here is questionable as exceptions should be used for exceptional cases - invalid user input is an everyday event.

On the form you use the errors object to diplay the validation errors to the user:

```
<%= form_with(model: @page) do |f| %>
  <% # @todo extract this into a partial %>
  <% if f.object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(f.object.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this page from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
  
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Since the Object is not invalid based on the [Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67438667/rails-why-cant-i-save-a-new-model-instance-to-the-database#comment119200410_67438667) you might want to run through validation?

Comment: Hello, thanks. Now it complains about `undefined local variable or method 'page_params' for #<PagesController:0x000056544f0af830>`

Comment: Hello engineersmnky, obviously alot changed since I last used Rails. Do I have to even more than strong-parameterizing the params hash now? I mean, I will read the validations guide for rails 6, but could you quickly/kindly tell me, what/how I would have to validate what in the model?

Comment: The method `page_params` is defined in the example - read it again and adapt it to your code. You don't actually have to do anything besides calling `#save` to validate the model. That triggers all the validations and returns false unless the record is valid and saved to the db.

Comment: Im also about 90% sure that the issue is that you have overriden the setter that ActiveRecord generated for `slug` in your Page model. By using `attr_accessor` for example. The setter need to trigger rails dirty tracking and set the attribute in the attributes hash for anything to happen with the db.

Comment: I did define `page_parameters` but it doesn't get hoisted or something obviously.

Comment: Yes I use attr_accessor for the models attributes. How else to define them ?

Comment: Methods are not hoisted in Ruby (nor do they need to be). I'm guessing its a "slop error" like for example that the method is actually defined outside the class or inside of another method.

Comment: Do not use attr_accessor in Rails models. ActiveRecord will automatically create setters/getter based on your database schema. If you have attributes that don't correspond to a database column use the attributes API. https://metova.com/rails-5-attributes-api/

Comment: I commented out attr_accessor. As I said, obviously a lot has changed since I last used Rails. Thanks for your ace help. Now I got a problem with the view corresponding to the #show-action. But I guess I will get that solved. If not, it's problem-domain is another-one anyway. Thanks for solving the problem. Good Bye max and engineersmnky